# Multiple nested iif statement in Access

Tags: ms-access, nested, iif

I am trying to calculate the number of vacation week an employee is entitled to using their years of service, with these categories:

```
0-4 years = 2 weeks
5-14 years = 3 weeks
15-24 years = 4 weeks
25 and up = 5 weeks
```

I found some examples and tried doing a nested iif statement but keep getting an error message. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
VacationWeeks: IIf([YearsInService]<=4, "2",
               IIf([YearsInService]is between 5 and 14, "3",
               IIf([YearsInService]is between 15 and 24, "4",
               IIf([YearsInService]>=25, "5", ”0”))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You are likely receiving error messages because of two issues with your code:

1. A [`BETWEEN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/between-and-operator-a435878d-63f7-4825-8c31-999432ae8223) statement has the syntax:

   ```
   expr [Not] Between value1 And value2
   ```

   You should *not* include the word **is**:

   ```
   IIf([YearsInService] is between 5 and 14,
                        ^-------------------- this shouldn't be here
   ```
2. Your final *else* argument encloses the string in 'smart quotes' or Unicode character [0x201C](http://graphemica.com/%E2%80%9C):

   ```
   IIf
   (
       [YearsInService] >= 25,
       "5",
       ”0” <--- here
   )
   ```

   As opposed to the standard double-quote, which is Unicode/ASCII character [0x0022](http://graphemica.com/%22):

   ```
   IIf
   (
       [YearsInService]>=25,
       "5",
       "0"
   )
   ```

Correcting these two issues would yield an [`IIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ECF-C629-48A3-9900-647539C764E3) statement such as:

```
IIf
(
    [YearsInService] <= 4,
    "2",
    IIf
    (
        [YearsInService] between 5 and 14,
        "3",
        IIf
        (
            [YearsInService] between 15 and 24,
            "4",
            IIf
            (
                [YearsInService] >= 25,
                "5",
                "0"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

However, you may find the use of a [`SWITCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) statement more readable:

```
Switch
(
    [YearsInService] <=  4, "2",
    [YearsInService] <= 14, "3",
    [YearsInService] <= 24, "4",
    [YearsInService] >  24, "5",
    True, "0"
)
```

The last test expression provides a catch-all default to account for nulls and still return a string value - I'll let you decide whether you wish to include or omit this, depending on the requirements of your application.